# How to run this feature file on multiple rows of data in excel sheet?

Tags: bdd, cucumber-java

I'm new to BDD and Cucumber. Here is my code.

My Excel file: 3 Rows (Top row is Header) and 4 Columns

Item        Description                                                     Model       Price
Iphone 13   Apple - Pre-Owned iPhone 13 Pro 5G 128GB (Unlocked) - Graphite  A2483-GRY   $879.99
iphone 12   Apple - iPhone 12 5G 64GB (Unlocked) - Black                    MGF43LL/A   $629.99

feature file:
Scenario: Search for item and Add to Cart
1 Given The data excel file name and location is given as
| Excel           | Location                           | Sheet  |
| searchdata.xlsx | src/test/resources/searchdata.xlsx | Sheet1 |
2 When open the site
3 And enter text to search field
4 And click the search icon
5 And wait for the search results to load
6 And find an item with description
7 And click on Add to Cart
8 Then verify that a popup appears with the text The item you added to cart

Steps Description File:

```
@Given("The data excel file name and location is given as")
public void the_data_excel_file_name_and_location_is_given_as(IDataReader dataTable) {
    // List<Map<String, String>> data = dataTable.getAllRows();
}

@When("open the site") 
    public void i_open_the_site() { 
     driver.get("site.com/");
     System.out.println("On site page");
}
 
 @And("search for an item") 
     public void i_search_for_item(IDataReader dataTable) { 
     System.out.println("Search for an Item");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gh-search-input\"]")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gh-search- 
     input\"]")).sendKeys(dataTable.getAllRows().get(0).get("Item")); 
}

@DataTableType
    public IDataReader excelToDataTable(Map<String, String> entry) { // [Excel= <fileName>, Location=<FileLocation> ..]
        ExcelConfiguration config = new ExcelConfiguration.ExcelConfigurationBuilder()
                .setFileName(entry.get("Excel"))
                .setFileLocation(entry.get("Location"))
                .setSheetName(entry.get("Sheet"))
                .setIndex(Integer.valueOf(entry.getOrDefault("Index", "0")))
                .build();
        return new ExcelDataReader(config);
                
    }
```

Running it via Runner class::

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/Features", glue= {"Definitions"}, monochrome = true,
plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/HtmlReports"}
)
public class TestRunner {

}

So In the first **Given** step I'm able to get all excelsheet data in a Java List of Maps.
In the steps 3 & 6, I want to pick column 1 and 2nd row and 3rd row data.

I have 2 questions:

1. How to run this feature file on multiple rows of data in excel sheet. I have 2 rows of data.
2. What should I write in feature file on steps 3 and 6 to know I need only column 1, 2nd row and 3rd row data.

Thanks